# Getting high query execution time in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

```
Table: Customer

Type:

telephone1  | character varying(255)
telephone2  | character varying(255)
location_id | integer 

Index:

"idx_customers_location_id" btree (location_id)
"idx_customers_telephone1_txt" btree (telephone1 text_pattern_ops)
"idx_customers_trim_telephone_1" btree (btrim(telephone1::text))
"idx_customers_trim_telephone2" btree (btrim(telephone2::text))
```

I have a table called customers, total rows are **141182**. I was checking values in two columns (telephone1, telephone2), all the column telephone1 has data, but only 8 rows have value for the column telephone2

When I check for the *value 1*, getting this below execution time.

```
SELECT  customers.id, location_id, telephone1, telephon2 FROM "customers" INNER JOIN "locations" ON 
"locations"."id" = "customers"."location_id" WHERE (customers.location_id = 189 AND (telephone1 = '1'
OR telephone2 = '1')) GROUP BY customers.id LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;


Limit  (cost=519.62..519.64 rows=4 width=125) (actual time=25.895..25.898 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=519.62..519.64 rows=4 width=125) (actual time=25.893..25.896 rows=1 loops=1)
         Group Key: customers.id
         ->  Sort  (cost=519.62..519.62 rows=4 width=127) (actual time=25.876..25.879 rows=1 loops=1)
               Sort Key: customers.id
               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=8.62..519.61 rows=4 width=127) (actual time=10.740..25.869 rows=1 loops=1)
                     ->  Index Scan using locations_pkey on locations  (cost=0.06..4.06 rows=1 width=70) (actual time=0.027..0.029 rows=1 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (id = 189)
                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on customers  (cost=8.56..515.54 rows=4 width=61) (actual time=10.707..25.832 rows=1 loops=1)
                           Recheck Cond: (((telephone1)::text = '1'::text) OR ((telephone2)::text = '1'::text))
                           Filter: (location_id = 189)
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 1048
                           Heap Blocks: exact=1737
                           ->  BitmapOr  (cost=8.56..8.56 rows=259 width=0) (actual time=3.445..3.446 rows=0 loops=1)
                                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_customers_telephone1_txt  (cost=0.00..2.10 rows=7 width=0) (actual time=0.065..0.066 rows=99 loops=1)
                                       Index Cond: ((telephone1)::text = '1'::text)
                                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_customers_telephone2_txt  (cost=0.00..6.47 rows=253 width=0) (actual time=3.378..3.378 rows=1664 loops=1)
                                       Index Cond: ((telephone2)::text = '1'::text)
 Planning Time: 0.419 ms
 Execution Time: 25.995 ms
```

When I check for *value 0* there is a huge change in the execution time (**7753.216 ms**)

```
Limit  (cost=0.14..2440.90 rows=10 width=125) (actual time=5900.924..7753.133 rows=4 loops=1)
   ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.14..292402.20 rows=1198 width=125) (actual time=5900.922..7753.129 rows=4 loops=1)
         Group Key: customers.id
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.14..292395.61 rows=1198 width=127) (actual time=4350.358..7753.087 rows=4 loops=1)
               ->  Index Scan using customers_pkey on customers  (cost=0.09..292387.36 rows=1198 width=61) (actual time=4350.338..7753.054 rows=4 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((location_id = 189) AND (((telephone1)::text = '0'::text) OR ((telephone2)::text = '0'::text)))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 8484280
               ->  Materialize  (cost=0.06..4.06 rows=1 width=70) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=4)
                     ->  Index Scan using locations_pkey on locations  (cost=0.06..4.06 rows=1 width=70) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=1 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (id = 189)
 Planning Time: 0.322 ms
 Execution Time: 7753.216 ms
```

Is there any particular reason, that takes more time to execute for the *value 0* ? or anything wrong here?

One more thing I have noticed this issue happens only with column telephone2.

Comment: What happens when you change the WHERE condition: WHERE (customers.location_id = 189 AND (btrim(telephone1::text) = '0' OR btrim(telephone2::text) = '0'))  ? Or is it that you have too many records that match these conditions?

Comment: Thanks, Frank for your comment, I have tried with the way which you mentioned, but still getting more than 7second, As I mentioned in the question, I have a total of 141182 records. But I am getting the result for search value 1 with 25 ms.

Comment: Is the value 0 a default value for this column?

Comment: @FrankHeikens, there is no default value, basically, we are storing the telephone number in those 2 columns, column telephone1 has always value, but the column telephone2 could be empty, the query works fine when we look for a value telephone2 = 1, but if I am doing telephone2 = 0 then it takes more time.

Answer (score 0):

> but only 8 rows have value for the column telephone2

Your explain plan indicates otherwise, finding 1664 rows with one specific value for telephone2.  Now maybe most of those are not visible, but in that case you really need to VACUUM ANALYZE the table.

> ```
> Nested Loop  (cost=0.14..292395.61 rows=1198 width=127) (actual time=4350.358..7753.087 rows=4 loops=1)
> ```

With this second query, it thinks it will find 1198 rows (if run to completion).  But it thinks it can stop after the first 20, so that would be 1.67% of index.  But instead there are only 4 rows, so it unexpectedly has to scan the entire index without getting to stop early.

Why are the estimates off by so much?  I don't know, it could just be stale statistics (again, VACUUM ANALYZE the table), or there could be some interrelation between the columns that make the estimation hard to do even with accurate statistics.

What is the point in joining to locations at all?

Comment: Join with location: Because we have to select some fields from the location table, also this telephone search happens based on the location.

Comment: But you have shown use your query, and it isn't selecting any fields from locations (and if it did, your GROUP BY would then be illegal) and the only restriction based on location is driven by the location_id, which is present in customers.

Comment: We are selecting some attributes From the location, but yeah I missed to add that in the query, also I have to use these customers.id in the group by clause @jjanes